# Execution of test automation in selenium is not executed

Tags: javascript, selenium, automated-tests, webdriver-io

I have a test automation project here that has stopped running for some reason and need help figuring out why and how to fix it.
Its a project for testing a website with selenium in javascript.

I get the following output on the terminal:

```
PS C:\company\selenium> npm run test-live-local
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

> webdriverio-automation-v6@1.0.0 test-live-local
> npx wdio wdio.live.local.conf.js

npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

"Here is actually the robot from chars represented. (I have deleted for better representation)"

                           Webdriver.IO
              Next-gen browser and mobile automation
                    test framework for Node.js

node:internal/bootstrap/switches/does_own_process_state:112
  rawMethods.chdir(directory);
             ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, chdir 'C:\company\selenium' -> 'C:\company\selenium\wdio.live.local.conf.js'
    at process.wrappedChdir [as chdir] (node:internal/bootstrap/switches/does_own_process_state:112:14)
    at createWebdriverIO (C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\471611576716610c\node_modules\wdio\build\index.js:66:13) {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'chdir',
  path: 'C:\\company\\selenium',
  dest: 'C:\\company\\selenium\\wdio.live.local.conf.js'
}
```